# How can I make the equation of warped disk?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, moment-of-inertia, galaxies, milky-way

My teacher gave us the assignment to find the moment of inertia of any shape you want. So I decided to find the moment of inertia of our milky way galaxy.

I found out that our galaxy is shaped like a warped disk, not a flat. After I found out that, I looked for the equation of the shape and density distribution of the Milky Way to find its **I**.
But, to me, Nasa's and some high university papers had so many big wards that I could bearly understand what they were talking about(I'm Korean.. ^^). I'm sure that I can understand the equation if I had it, but I just can't find any information about them.

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what you know about this equation(shape & density distribution)

Thank you!

[image: Dorota M. Skowron, A three-dimensional map of the Milky Way using classical Cepheid variable stars]
(Img)Dorota M. Skowron, A three-dimensional map of the
Milky Way using classical Cepheid
variable stars

Comment: I suspect that your teacher meant for you to choose a simple geometrical shape, like a disk, a cube, a sphere, a torus, an icosahedron, etc.

Comment: Because I'm in science high school, we already learned all kinds of simple geometrical shapes, so sadly, I can't use those..

Comment: You’ve previously computed the moment of inertia of an icosahedron and you’re in high school? I’m impressed.

Comment: Is this for a multivariable calculus class?

Comment: No, this is for my physics class report. Because this class has a lot of credit, I  want to be as good as I can.

Comment: You find the moment of inertia of an irregular three-dimensional shape using a volume integral. If you aren't supposed to know how to solve volume integrals, you may be misunderstanding the subject of the assignment. One can reduce the problem to one dimension with some significant simplifying assumptions, so that single-variable calculus can be used - but only by approximating the galaxy-shaped galaxy as a radially symmetric thin disk.

Comment: We learned how to calculate a 3D rigid body with Spherical, cylindrical coordinates, and other coordinate systems. But, as you said, finding our galaxy's three-dimensional shape seems hard. I'd better change my shape. TThanks anyway!^^